# SharedPreferences error in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter

I was using `shared_preferences` plugin in my Flutter application. From one moment (probably after Flutter upgrade), it started to throw an exception:

```
E/flutter (27778): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (27778): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Object>' where
E/flutter (27778):   _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
E/flutter (27778):   Map is from dart:core
E/flutter (27778):   String is from dart:core
E/flutter (27778):   Object is from dart:core
E/flutter (27778): 
E/flutter (27778): #0      SharedPreferences.getInstance (package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart)
E/flutter (27778): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27778): #1      loadFirstUse (**path**/lib/main.dart:29:53)
E/flutter (27778): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27778): #2      main (**path**/lib/main.dart:17:9)
E/flutter (27778): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27778): #3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:279:19)
E/flutter (27778): #4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
```

It happens when I simple try to create instance of SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

I was trying to find root of the problem, but was unable to find it. Thank you for any help.

EDIT: I am using   `shared_preferences: "^0.4.0"`

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10872

Comment: I had this problem using the Dart 2.0 preview. I guess that should be fixed using shared_preferences 0.4.0, which version are you using?

Comment: @Rene I am using   `shared_preferences: "^0.4.0"`

Comment: @NileshRathod Tried to change to "0.2.4" as you suggested, no difference

Comment: No idea if this will help, but perhaps you could try doing `flutter clean` as well as `pub cache repair` to see if you can shake things out

Comment: `pub cache repair` shouldn't be necessary. I need `flutter clean` frequently though to ensure changes take effect.

Comment: Tried to `pub cache repair` and `flutter clean`, nothing helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried `shared_preferences: "0.2.4"` and other versions suggested above without any success.  Finally got it to work after changing flutter channel from dev to beta:

```
flutter channel beta
```

At least this fixes this problem for now and just wait for a fix for the shared_preferences plugin on the dev channel.

Comment: I tried this but get the message `git: Already on 'beta'` and I am already using `0.2.4` Still get the same error.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this using the following workaround:

```
Future<SharedPreferences> prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.then(
  (pref)
  {
    //call functions like pref.getInt(), etc. here
  }
);
```

Answer (score 6):

To debug this, use the following:

```
Future<SharedPreferences> _sprefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
_sprefs.then((prefs) {
  // ...
}, 
onError: (error) {
  print("SharedPreferences ERROR = $error");   
});
```

In my case the error was that I wanted to call `await SharedPreferences.getInstance()` before I called `runApp()`, so that solution the error message gave me was to order my code as follows:

First:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Afterwards:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Finally:

```
runApp(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by changing to `shared_preferences: "0.3.3"`. There is a good chance this breaks again.

Comment: I still get the same error after changing to `0.3.3`

Comment: @Guus, yeah, not exactly sure why the fix worked for us. We ended up switching our entire state management to Redux. If you want to continue using shared_preferences, maybe try some other version numbers to see if they fix the issue. Sorry I can't give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Future like this

```
Future<SharedPreferences> _sprefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Comment: Need a more complete example. Can you show code to get a preference, please?

Answer (score 0):

I remove packages one by one, and found that it was caused by `flutter_barcode_scanner`. I upgraded it to version 2.0.0 and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was working fine earlier but now I am getting **invalid format exception while calling SharedPreferences.getInstance();**

and for solution I tried everything but nothing work.so at last I create new project and paste all my previous code. and that's finally solve the problem