# SharedPreferences.getInstance() is throwing _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and still learning. I am trying to get reference of SharedPreferences instance but I am getting following error

> _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

This is how my code looks like

*app_settings.dart*

```
class AppSettings {
  
  final SharedPreferences _pref;
  
  AppSettings._(this._pref);

  static AppSettings? _instance;

  static initialize() async {
    if (_instance != null) {
      // already initialized
      return;
    }
    // instance not found. creating one
   
    var pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _instance = AppSettings._(pref);

  }
}
```

main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // initializing application settings
  await AppSettings.initialize();
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "hello app",
        home: AppHome());
  }
}
```

Upon further debugging I found that the exception is being thrown by *invokeMapMethod* in

> flutter-sdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart

which is called by *getAll* method in

> flutter-sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_platform_interface-2.0.0/lib/method_channel_shared_preferences.dart

Below are the screenshots of error

[image: invokeMapMethod]

[image: getAll]

Comment: Which version of flutter and shared_preferences are you using?

Comment: Flutter 2.2.3, shared_preferences: ^2.0.6 and dart 2.13.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was calling `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` before `runApp()`. Since platform-specific native bindings were not initialized, which are used by `SharedPreferences`, it was throwing a null exception. So I added `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before calling `await SharedPreferences.getInstance()`:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // initializing application settings
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AppSettingService.initialize();
  runApp(WorkoutTrackerApp());
}
```

You can learn more from following links

- [SharedPreferences error in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407237/sharedpreferences-error-in-flutter)
- [What Does WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873338/what-does-widgetsflutterbinding-ensureinitialized-do/)
- [`ensureInitialized` method documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
static initialize async() {
  _instance = _instance?AppSettings(await SharedPreferences.getInstance());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if (preferences == null) return {} as Map;
```